# nested loop number of execution

Tags: nested-loops

I can never understand how to calculate the number of times the inner loop in a nested loop is being executed. I thought when we have nested loop, the number of execution of first one is multiplied by the second (inner) one but I found out that they use sigma and ... ex.

```
for i <- n − 1 down to 0 do
   for j <- 1 to i do
     if A[j − 1] > A[j] then
        swap(A[j], A[j − 1])

exact number of execution => (n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 = sigma[i=1 -> n-1] i = n(n-1)/2
```

for these kind of loops, I always try to write down what's going on. for example for this one I did like this:

```
i = 0 => j = - 
i = 1  => j = 1
.
.
.
i = n-1 => j = 1,2,3, ... , n-1
```

but then I don't know what to do :/

I really need help thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have given, the j in the inner loop depends on i from the outer loop (j<=i).

You have enumerated correctly the executions taking place.

You will get:

> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1

This is a Gaussian sum. The formula we use to compute sums of consecutive numbers from 1 to N is **sum = N*(N+1)/2**.

In this case, N = n-1, so the sum (total number of inner loop runs) will be: (n-1)*n/2.

I hope this clears that out.

The case you mentioned at first:

> I thought when we have nested loop, the number of execution of first
>   one is multiplied by the second (inner) one

is true when the inner loop is not dependent on the outer loop (in this case, if j were not dependent on i).